# Get subset of query result

Tags: mysql, sql, union

The table `request` has foreign key fields `job` and `user`.  I need to pull the subset of rows for which one user has both a row for both `job` = 35 and `job` = 34.

Is this query doing the job correctly?  I believe it is.

```
SELECT * FROM `request` 
WHERE `job` = 35 AND `fulfilled` is NULL 
AND 
`user` IN 
(SELECT `user` FROM `request` WHERE `job` = 34 AND `fulfilled` is NULL )
```

Comment: Where is the `UNION`? Also, you should refrain from using `SELECT *`. Always specify a column list. Why can't you just use a single query? `(SELECT user FROM request WHERE job IN (34, 35) AND fulfilled IS NULL)`?

Comment: Do you need the rows or just the user? Your original query is only returning the rows where job='35'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT user
FROM   request
WHERE  job IN (34,35) AND `fulfilled` is NULL 
GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT job) = 2
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a627c/1)

Comment: Thank you and thank you for the SQLFiddle link; was not aware of them!